Cannot access URL from java, but can from browser (Chrome)
I'm developing an application that fetches data from homepages. I'm encountering an issue with accessing a specific URL: "https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/218824/intel-w790-chipset/specifications.html". While I can access this URL from my browser (Chrome) without any problems, attempting to connect from my Java app. results in a 403 status code (forbidden). Could anyone provide guidance on how to resolve this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
The relevant code:
 String url = "https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/218824/intel-w790-chipset/specifications.html";

        try {
            boolean redirected = false;
            URL obj = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

            // Set request method to GET
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            // Add request headers
            conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");

            // Set the cookies allowed property
            conn.setAllowUserInteraction(true);

            // Handle the response
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    ...



When I comment out the line conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",... it works for me.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk hehe. That's funny

"User-Agent" fails
As commented by Polk, the offending line is:
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36");

With that line, we see:

responseCode = 403
message = Forbidden

If we comment-out that line, the rest runs well on Java 22.
String url = "https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/218824/intel-w790-chipset/specifications.html";

boolean redirected = false;
URL obj = null;
try
{
    obj = new URL( url );
    HttpURLConnection conn = ( HttpURLConnection ) obj.openConnection( );

    // Set request method to GET
    conn.setRequestMethod( "GET" );

    // Add request headers
    //conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36");
    conn.setRequestProperty( "Accept" , "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8" );
    conn.setRequestProperty( "Accept-Language" , "en-US,en;q=0.5" );
    conn.setRequestProperty( "Accept-Encoding" , "gzip, deflate, br" );
    conn.setRequestProperty( "Connection" , "keep-alive" );

    // Set the cookies allowed property
    conn.setAllowUserInteraction( true );

    // Handle the response
    final int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode( );
    final String message = conn.getResponseMessage( );

    System.out.println( "responseCode = " + responseCode );
    System.out.println( "message = " + message );
} catch ( MalformedURLException e )
{
    throw new RuntimeException( e );
} catch ( ProtocolException e )
{
    throw new RuntimeException( e );
} catch ( IOException e )
{
    throw new RuntimeException( e );
}


responseCode = 200
message = OK

Avoid legacy classes
The HttpURLConnection API is now legacy.
JEP 321: HTTP Client
A modern HTTP client implementation arrived in Java 11+. See JEP 321: HTTP Client. See also the project page, Java HTTP Client on the OpenJDK site.
